# Syntax error: Bad for loop variable in linux shell scripting

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#File name: bai5.sh
clear

echo "Nhap so n:"
read n

sum=1

for((i=2;i<=$n;i++))
do
ketqua=`expr $sum + $i`
done

echo "Sum: $sum"
```

I get:

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You aren't actually running your script with `bash`. Use `bash bai5.sh` or `./bai5.sh`, not `sh bai5.sh`.

Comment: Also, it seems odd to use a `.sh` suffix for a script that is relying on bashisms.  Best bet is to stop the practice of using a `.sh` suffix at all. (As a user, I don't care if your program was written in sh, java, perl, php, or ada).  But if you're going to perpetuate that bad practice, call this one `bai5.bash`